# foreach successive folder creation, Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, foreach

This script has to work for powershell 2.0.
I dont know the syntactical differences to v5.1

At first latest written files of that day are bing piped into an array variable: $latestfile.
The folder structure is copied via  robocopy. The latestfiles in $latestfilehave to be then copied into a folder that is newly created, and added to the folder structure. The $latestfiles are .xml files, in a folder, with the daynumber as title. In a folder with year and month as title (202402 e.g.) the daily new folder is being created. the daily new folder has the daynumber as title, if it is "1" a new folder is created. the problem I have is now to create a folder, for every $latestfile via foreach, and copy the files there.

file structure:

[image]

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Ziel\MYBOFFID.901\2019\1104\fiscal.xml
                                .           .    .
                                .           .    .
                              MYBOFID.968\2024\tttt\fiscal.xml
```

The last foreach loop should create a folder for every $latestfile. only on folder with the daynumber is created on  the wrong level, not where the daily folders are.

At first I robocopy the structure so far. Then daily the latestfile is being piped.
In For every station (MYBOFFID) there is a latest file, for each on a new daily folder with title as the daynumber of that month is created. But this foreach loop at the end only produces one created new folder, and not on the right level.

```
robocopy "C:\Users\User\Documents\Ziel" "C:\Users\User\Documents\Testziel" /s 
$latestfile = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Testziel' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter '*.xml' -File -Recurse |
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime |
        Select-Object FullName, @{ N = 'Parent'; E = { $_.Directory.Parent } } -Last 1 
        
}

$path = Get-ChildItem $latestfile -Name "FilePath"
echo Path: $path

echo latestfile: $latestfile

#$folder_number = $latestfile.Parent.Name

echo folder number: $folder_number

echo $latestfile.Parent

$date = Get-Date

$year_month = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m"
echo year_month: $year_month

$day = $date.ToString("dd")
echo day: $day


foreach($i in $latestfile){
New-Item -Path C:\Users\User\Documents\Testziel\$day -Type Directory
}
```

Comment: You need to move more code into the foreach loop.  $day never changes.  It is always the same value.

Comment: Sorry, but why on earth do you need to use PoSH 2.0? There is a portable version of PWSH 7.x available that works on legacy systems as well. Although it's not supported by MS, but so isn't PoSH 2.0 any more.

Comment: @jdweng your problem is in 
`foreach($i in $latestfile){
New-Item -Path C:\Users\User\Documents\Testziel\$day -Type Directory
}`

Comment: @Dennis, organizations have a variety of logic for using older versions of software. The security risk of PowerShell 2.0 does not appear to be part of the OP's organization logic.

Comment: I'm more concerned with speed and features :) In many instances PoSH 2.0 just doesn't cut it any more, by a long way. But in this specific case, where only addressing a simple foreach loop.

Comment: @Dennis: the user has a Windows 2008 R2 Server, and the powershell version 2.0, I will discuss the possibility  today of maybe upgrading the powershell of the user. Maybe the best solution

Comment: Do mind that if the server are using legacy applications built for PowerShell, they might only work with Windows PowerShell 2.0.

Comment: @dcaz: Yes, that loop, I just want that for every item $i, a new folder is generated, but in the right place, successively